# It seems numpy array automatically ignores decimals

Tags: python, numpy, gradient

It seems numpy array automatically ignores delta_x. The output of the following gradient vector is gigantic. What change should be made to the following code for gradient?

```
import copy
import numpy as np

def numerical_gradient(f, x):
    delta_x = 1e-7    # 0.0000001
    gradient = np.zeros_like(x)    # Return an array of zeros with the same shape

    for i in range(x.size): 
        # constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, 
        # inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original
        _x1 = copy.deepcopy(x)    
        _x1[i] = x[i] + delta_x
        _y1 = f(_x1)    # f(x + delta_x)

        _x2 = copy.deepcopy(x)
        _x2[i] = x[i] - delta_x
        _y2 = f(_x2)    # f(x - delta_x)

        gradient[i] = (_y1 - _y2) / (delta_x*2)
    return gradient

def f(x):
    y = x[0]**2 + x[1]**2
    return y

numerical_gradient(f,np.array([3,3]))
```

Comment: show some example where it doesn't works

Comment: There are multiple obfuscations in your code. You can completely remove the for loop, there is no need for making a copy of x you can just do x1 = x - delta_x.

Comment: Thanks for helping me trimming the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
numerical_gradient(f,np.array([3,3]))
```

This initializes an integer array; with `deepcopy` and `zeros_like` you create more integer arrays. You attempt to assign 2.999999 to an integer array element in _x2, which gets rounded to 2.

If you do this:

```
numerical_gradient(f,np.array([3.0, 3.0]))
```

the output is as expected.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works! I was blind to see the input mistake lol.

Comment: You can also explicitly specify the `dtype` of the array.